# Plot marks filled and drawn, but not the path

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to have it so that the plot marks would be filled and drawn, but the actual path wouldn't be drawn?

Here is example where it is otherwise the way I'd like, except those dots' should be filled with white:

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,plotmarks,scopes}
\tikzpicture[bend right, out=60, in=120, max distance=1.5cm]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,8} {
    \coordinate (n\x) at (\x,0);
  }
  \draw (n1) to (n3) to (n5) to (n7) to (n1);
  \draw (n8) to (n6) to (n4) to (n2) to (n8);
  \path plot[fill=white,draw=black,mark=*]
    coordinates{(1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0) (6,0) (7,0) (8,0)};
\endtikzpicture
```

[image]

And here the dots are the way I would like, but the path is (of course) drawn:

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,plotmarks,scopes}
\tikzpicture[bend right, out=60, in=120, max distance=1.5cm]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,8} {
    \coordinate (n\x) at (\x,0);
  }
  \draw (n1) to (n3) to (n5) to (n7) to (n1);
  \draw (n8) to (n6) to (n4) to (n2) to (n8);
  \filldraw[fill=white,draw=black] plot[mark=*]
    coordinates{(1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0) (6,0) (7,0) (8,0)};
\endtikzpicture
```

[image]

Is there a way to combine the two so that the dots look like in the latter, and the paths like in the former?

Comment: You can include `plot` command into `foreach`. This way you plot marks and declare coordinates at same time and can forget two last lines. Something like this worked for me: `\foreach \x in {1,...,8} {\path plot[mark=*, mark options={fill=white}]  coordinates{(\x,0)} coordinate (n\x); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to supply the `fill` only to the markers. You can do that using `mark options={fill=white}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,plotmarks,scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bend right, out=60, in=120, max distance=1.5cm]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,8} {
    \coordinate (n\x) at (\x,0);
  }
  \draw (n1) to (n3) to (n5) to (n7) to (n1);
  \draw (n8) to (n6) to (n4) to (n2) to (n8);
  \path plot[mark=*, mark options={fill=white}]
    coordinates{(1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0) (6,0) (7,0) (8,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I saw that option in the manual but didn't realize it could be used here. Thanks! (Amazingly fast answer, too!)